# DetailView running twice before display

Tags: python, django, view

I have a DetailView which is running twice if url hit once.

What i am exactly looking for is whenever someone hits the detail view url, the view_count field in that particular DetailView's model needs to be incremented by 1 and the constraint is this should not happen when a person view his own record.

I am getting the output for exactly what i am looking for but the only thing is the value is getting incremented twice.

views.py

```
python
class PortfolioDetailedView(DetailView):
    model = Portfolio
    slug_field = 'slug'

class PortfolioDetailedView(DetailView):
    model = Portfolio
    success_url = 'portfolio:index'

    def get_object(self):
        obj = super().get_object() #got the model object(Portfolio object)
        if not str(obj.person.username)==str(self.request.user.username):
            obj.view_count+=1
            obj.save() #saving updates
        return obj #returning object
```

logs while getting data

```
[17/Jul/2020 19:53:18] "GET /portfolio/detail/test2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14893
[17/Jul/2020 19:53:20] "GET /portfolio/detail/test2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14893
```

models.py

```
 class Portfolio(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE,related_name='portfolio')
    .....
    view_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
...........
```

Comment: Why are you calling `get_object()` and returning its value. What does the function contains?? If you haven't defined, the program must generate **NameError**

Comment: i have updated my question please letme know if any additional details required

Answer (score 0):

Returning `get_object()` rather than `obj` in your example is likely causing some issues and feels a bit redundant. Overriding the higher level `get` or `dispatch` methods and using `get_object` feels a little more natural to me if you want to perform some business logic in your view:

```
class PortfolioDetailedView(DetailView):
    model = Portfolio
    slug_field = 'slug'

    def dispatch(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_object()
        obj.view_count += 1
        obj.save()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: still not working  all the default method from the DetailView are running twice and data is getting fetched twice and the logic written is getting executed twice. for suppose based on above logic for every redirect of DetailView class page the count need to be updated once but it is getting updated twice

Comment: Are you hitting the view by typing in the address in your browser or are you using a link in one of your pages? It's likely that this issue caused by something outside of this `DetailView`. Are there any more details you could provide? Is this happening for other views in your project or just this one? Other related code?

Comment: I have tried both the ways but getting same results. I have updated the code a bit have a look . its happening only for that detailView class.